# Visual Studio 2012 For Each Loop Displays Numbers Into ListBox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, foreach, listbox

Hey everyone I don't understand how the for each loop works in this particular situation. I have a 500 gallon tank of water will be used in a Fish Fry 24 hours from now. The tank as a leak rate of 10% of the remaining water every hour. If the tank drops below 100 gallons the fish will all die (instantly). Here is the catch, adding additional gallons of water per hour to keep final value above 100 gallons. Then display the number of gallons remaining after each hour in the listbox.

Here is a picture of the program to see which controls I am using:

[image]

I need help with getting the logic down.

```
500 * .10 = 50
500 - 50 = 450
```

so on and so on... But I need all the math calculation to print out to the listBox like so:

[image]

Any help is appreciated, I am learning so don't be to harsh. 
Here is my Code:

```
      Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim Gallons As Double = 500
    Dim LeakRate As Double = 0.1
    Dim Remainder As Integer
    Dim Time As Integer = tkbSlider.Value
    lstRemainingGallons.Items.Clear()
    For n As Integer = 1 To 24
        Remainder = CInt(Gallons * LeakRate) - Time
        Gallons = CInt(Gallons - Remainder)
        If Gallons <= 99 Then

            MessageBox.Show("Fish died at " & n & " hours when the remaining gallons were " & Gallons, "Dead and Stinking Fish", MessageBoxButtons.OK
                )
            Exit Sub
        End If
        **If Gallons <= 100 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Hello You Have Passed", "Fish Frying Time!")
        End If**
        lstRemainingGallons.Items.Add("Hour # " & n & " -  " & Gallons & "gallons")

    Next

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I can see that it is winforms, but what are you using for the language C# or Vb.net

Comment: vb.net I was going upload my code... But it doesn't have any working calculations.

Comment: Are you needing to use a for each loop or just a for loop, A for each loop would normally be used to iterate through a collection.

Comment: I realize that this is homework so I don't just want to give you the answer, but you need to iterate through each hour, normally this would be a for loop, subtracting capacity * leakrate from capacity and assigning it to capacity, you would then use the ListBox.Items.Add to add the results to the Listbox

Comment: `for n as integer = 1 to 24` do your hour based calcs

Comment: @MarkHall When i write the loop to iterate the code using the hours i get the same repeated answer.. What am I doing wrong? I added the code.

Comment: @user2872778 You are always using Gallons which is 500, You are not changing it, Try something like `Gallons = Gallons - Remainder` and use Gallons in your print statement, no need for a numberOfGallons variable, you are just duplicating your math

Comment: @MarkHall I think i got the program working other than I can't seem to get the validation of whether the amount of leftover gallons is above 100 to print out a message to a message box.. Other than that it works like a charm. The second if statement just is being ignored...

Comment: You are checking if the Gallons <= 100 which is saying show the message if it is  less than or equal to 100 you need to change it to gallons >= 100 or just change your if statement to an if/else statement.

Answer (score 1):

If I could go back to when I started programming and teach myself only one thing it would be the basics of using a debugger.

It would really help you to learn the debugging features of visual studio. It is probably the single most important thing you could do to get better at solving debugging problems. I'd suggest learning the following to start:

1. Step In/Step Out/Step Over - learn how to slowly step through code line by line
2. Breakpoints - learn how to stop a program at a particular point so you can see if the program makes it to a certain line, and what the variable values are at that line.
3. Watching variables - see the value of a variable while debugging.

see this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-2010-A-Beginn

Oh and don't get overwhelmed and feel you need to get through everything in that article.

If you can figure our 1,2, and 3 above you'll be off to a good start.
You want to put a breakpoint in your method and step through the code.  You can see what the values of the variables are, and what the value of the variable is that you are printing in your print statement.

That one is for c# - you can also look at this: (or just google debugging in vb .net )

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/94249-debugging/